# Flutter, WebView empty page using Provider

Tags: flutter, webview, provider

I have Provider on top of MyApp, and the webview is still opening with a blank screen.
No errors, no suggestions it just opening with a blank screen and not loading.
If i put a web address in the url is working fine but i want to have this dynamic.

```
runApp(
    Provider<Events>.value(
      value: Events(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
```

```
class Events {
  final String imagePath, site;

Events({
  this.imagePath, this.site
});

final events = [
  castel,
  lake,
];
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../model/events.dart';
import './flutter_web.dart';

class Site extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final events = Provider.of<Events>(context);

    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: Container(
        child: IconButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => FlutterWeb(events.site),
            ),
          ),
          icon: Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.internetExplorer,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
return WebView(
          initialUrl: events.site,
        )
```

Comment: What is definition of MyApp, FlutterWeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In `value` attribute, you need to pass variable not class 
In your code snippet `events` is `array` it might be a typo

code snippet

```
void main() {
  final events = Events(imagePath: "castel", site: "https://flutter.dev/");

  runApp(
    Provider<Events>.value(
      value: events,
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class Events {
  final String imagePath, site;

  Events({this.imagePath, this.site});
}

void main() {
  final events = Events(imagePath: "castel", site: "https://flutter.dev/");

  runApp(
    Provider<Events>.value(
      value: events,
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Site());
  }
}

class Site extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var events = Provider.of<Events>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Container(
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => FlutterWeb(events.site),
                ),
              ),
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.internetExplorer,
                size: 30.0,
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FlutterWeb extends StatelessWidget {
  String site;
  FlutterWeb(this.site);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: site,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't want to put final events under void main(), i have already decleared in my model/events.dart, there is a list of 30 site paths

Comment: what about if I want to add to Navigator => FlutterWeb(events.site) the imagePath?

Comment: question 1, you can directly final events = Events()

Comment: questions 2, if you events has 30 elements. you can do Navigator => FlutterWeb(events[index])  to pass Event item directly.  and use it with WebView(
      initialUrl: event.site,
    )

Comment: i've tried with MapBox(events[index])  but i have error: "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Events'

Comment: please define a list and use like List<Events> eventList = [Events(), Events(), Events()];